# C++: How to print two ASCII pictures side by side?

Tags: c++, ascii

So i need to make a method that takes two ASCII pictures that i have created and prints them side by side, so the method call:

```
concatHz(Picture l, Picture r);
```

Where Picture is an object that stores the ASCII picture as a string in fields l.result and r.result.

If r was

```
+------+ 
|This  | 
|is the| 
|String| 
+------+
```

and l was:

```
This
is the
String
```

then the result would be:

```
This  +------+
is the|This  |
String|is the|
      |String|
      +------+
```

I have thought of ways of doing this, but they seem too complicated and there might be an easier way. I was thinking of using for loops to go through each string line and printing the first one and then the second, but then that runs into the problem of an indexing error as with the example above. Is there a simple way to do this that i am not thinking of?

Here is the method that creates the underlying ASCII picture:

```
Picture Picture::create(std::vector<std::string> v){
    Picture c;  //default constructor called without parenthesis
    c.picList=v;
    c.result="";
    int max1=0;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        if(v.at(i).length()>max1){
           max1=v.at(i).length();
        }
        c.rows++;
        c.result+=v.at(i)+"\n";
    }
    c.maxLen=max1;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What you are thinking of is as simple as it could be. Just have to "index" things correctly, and print a set of blank spaces instead of the nonexistent row for the first picture, for the last line. This is not rocket science. Just a simple exersize in logic.

Comment: It depends on what the `Picture` data structure looks like.

Comment: The main thing is that it stores a string called result as a representation of those ascii's with \n for the new lines.

Comment: It is hard to know what you are thinking of. "Using for loops" is about as informative as "using letters". Show the code.

Comment: I just posted the most relevant code to what the Picture method represents

Comment: Use two pointers for _C-string_ (or if your underlying structure is `std::vector` use two iterators) instead of indices. When pointer points to `\0`  stop printing for that string. When both pointers point to `\0`, terminate your `while` loop. Similarly, with iterators (check for `end()` instead of `\0` if strings are not null-terminated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't generate the complete picture as a single `std::string`, you need access to the individual `std::string` values that make up each `std::vector`.  That way, you can run a single loop, where each iteration outputs the next `l` string padded to `l.maxLen` characters, then outputs the next `r` string, then outputs a line break.  End the loop when both pictures have been exhausted.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Picture
{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> picList;
    std::size_t maxLen;
public:
    Picture();
    Picture(const std::vector<std::string> &v);

    static Picture create(const std::vector<std::string> &v);

    std::size_t getMaxRowLen() const;
    std::size_t getRows() const;
    std::string getRow(std::size_t index) const;

    // just in case you really need it
    std::string getResult() const;
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

Picture Picture::create(const std::vector<std::string> &v)
{
    return Picture(v);
}

Picture::Picture()
    : maxLen(0)
{
}

Picture::Picture(const std::vector<std::string> &v)
    : picList(v), maxLen(0)
{
    for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = picList.begin(); iter != picList.end(); ++iter) {
        if (iter->length() > maxLen) {
            maxLen = iter->length();
        }
    }
}

std::size_t Picture::getMaxRowLen() const
{
    return maxLen;
}

std::size_t Picture::getRows() const
{
    return picList.size();
}

std::string Picture::getRow(std::size_t index) const
{
    std::string row;
    if (index < picList.size()) {
        row = picList[index];
    }
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setw(maxLen) << std::left << std::setfill(' ') << row;
    return oss.str();
}

std::string Picture::getResult() const
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = picList.begin(); iter != picList.end(); ++iter) {
        oss << std::setw(maxLen) << std::left << std::setfill(' ') << *iter << "\n";
    }
    return oss.str();
}
```

```
void concatHz(const Picture &l, const Picture &r)
{
    std::size_t rows = std::max(l.getRows(), r.getRows());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        std::cout << l.getRow(i) << r.getRow(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a vector of strings to represent screen contents.

Just store your two ASCII art images in such a vector, then output.

Alternatively you can use cursor positioning via e.g. ncurses library.